# proof of 2 equations of Standard deviation

Tags: binomial-theorem, standard-deviation, mean-square-error

i have following question:

i can not prove why the following equations are the same:
$$
    \begin{align}
          A=(a_j),\ 1 \leqslant j \leqslant N. \\\\
          \mu = mean(A). \\\\
          S_1 = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (a_i - \mu)^2 }. = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (a_i^2 - 2 a_i \mu + \mu^2) } ] \\\\ 
          S_2 = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{N-1} \left[  \sum_{i=1}^{N} (a_i^2) - \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} (a_i) \right)^2}{N} \right] } \\          
    \end{align}
$$

why does $S_1 = S_2$?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like that you mixed up $i$ and $j$. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
S_1^2&=\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (a_i - \mu)^2 =\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (a_i^2-2\mu a_i +\mu^2)\\
&=\frac{1}{N-1} \left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i^2 +\sum_{i=1}^{N} \mu^2-2\mu\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i\right]=\frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i^2 +N \mu^2-2\mu N\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i^2 +N \mu^2-2N\mu^2 \right]=\frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i^2 -N\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i\right)^2}{N^2} \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N} (a_i^2) -\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i\right)^2}{N} \right]=S^2_2
\end{align}